# Java Simple Rotation Around Point

Tags: java, rotation, affinetransform

I'm trying to use this method to rotate a point:

```
 AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), 1, 2);
 double[] pt = {0, 1};
 at.transform(pt, 0, pt, 0, 1);
 int x = (int)pt[0];
 int y = (int)pt[1];
```

The expected result is `x=0` and `y=3` because we are rotating 90* clockwise, however the output is currently `x=2` and `y=1`;

Why am I not getting the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is doing nothing wrong.  By specifying `Math.toRadians(90)` as your theta, you are instructing it to rotate counter-clockwise, not clockwise.  That is how rotation is defined in trigonometry.

Using `-Math.toRadians(90)` would get you the correct result.

Also, as a side note, casting the point values to `int` isn't the best idea for checking your code.  Double-precision trigonometry is prone to very minor errors, and so a tiny bump in the wrong direction would get you the wrong integers.  (I.e., 2.99999999995 would be cast to 2)

`(int) Math.round(value)` is much safer

Comment: I figured it was something simple

Comment: So I need to use Math.Round on pt[0] and pt[1] - anywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you're rotating anti-clockwise. The Javadoc says:

> Rotating by a positive angle theta rotates points on the positive X axis toward the positive Y axis

See [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getRotateInstance%28double%29)